# Questions for building a HashMap in C

Tags: c, hashmap

I've encountered problems when I'm trying to build a hashMap using C. My goal is to build a hashMap with an array of linkedlist appended.

I'm now working on the insert element function, and here is the strange part. I hope to insert a newNode at the beginning. When I use a temp node head to store the "head" of this linkedlist and try to insert, it fails with no value insert. But if I change the head directly to "_hashmap->arrayOfLists[bucket]", then it works.. I do not know why and I think having a temp node should work.. Anyone can help with this? Thanks!

> typedef struct pair{
> char* key;
> char* value; }pair_t;
>
> typedef struct node{
> struct node* next;
> pair_t* kv;}node_t;

[Original problematic code]

> void hashmap_insert (hashmap_t* _hashmap, char* key, char* value){

> ```
>  pair_t* newPair = (pair_t*)malloc(sizeof(pair_t));
>  newPair->key = (char*)malloc(strlen(key) * sizeof(char)+1);
>  newPair->value = (char*)malloc(strlen(value) * sizeof(char)+1);
>
>  strcpy(newPair->key, key); //copy the input key into the malloc space.
>  strcpy(newPair->value, value); //copy the input value into the malloc space.
>
>  //create a newNode that is to be inserted.
>  node_t* newNode = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
>  newNode->kv = newPair;
>  newNode->next = NULL;
>
>
>  unsigned int bucket = _hashmap->hashFunction(key, _hashmap->buckets);
>
>  node_t* head = _hashmap->arrayOfLists[bucket];
>
>  // if the bucket is empty
>   if(head == NULL) {
>       head = newNode;
>   } else {//insert the newNode at the front.
>      newNode->next = head;
>       head = newNode;
>   }
> ```
>
> }

【The code that works]

> ```
>  if(_hashmap->arrayOfLists[bucket] == NULL) {
>      _hashmap->arrayOfLists[bucket] = newNode;
>  } else {
>      newNode->next = _hashmap->arrayOfLists[bucket];
>      _hashmap->arrayOfLists[bucket] = newNode;
>  }
> ```

Comment: `head` is a local variable. Changing it's value does nothing to the hash map.

Comment: I thought I create a pointer head that points to the "head" of that linkedList in the HashMap Array, and when I want to add a new Node, I can deal with the head directly ( as what I usually does in a linked list data structure). Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: `node_t` is a structure, so `head` is a pointer to a structure. It's not a pointer to a pointer. Changing the value of `head` just changes what `head` points to.

Comment: You can simplify "the code that works" by noting that the `if` and the `else` contain a line of code that is exactly the same for both. Furthermore, the first line of the `else` would just set `newNode->next` to NULL when the bucket pointer is NULL. So you don't need the `if` or the `else`, nor do you need the line of code `node->Next = NULL;` All you need is those two lines of code inside the `else`.

Comment: I get it ! That is really helpful!!Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You're welcome, best of luck on the project!